# Git: How can a git server find out which branch is pushing?

Tags: git, bash, unix

I run a git server and have some pre-receive hooks set up.  When someone pushes and this hook gets called, I would like to know which branch they are on.

Is there some sort of series of git commands that will allow me to do this?  It is absolutely crucial for what I need to do.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I don't think a push contains that information. In other words, if repo A pushes to repo B, repo B has no way of telling which is the current branch in repo A.

Comment: See the docs on the [pre-receive](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#pre-receive) hook. Specifically what it gets on standard input.

Comment: @EtanReisner, so you're saying I'll have to pass that information via standard input?

Comment: The branch they're on isn't relevant to the branch being pushed. I can be on branch `asdf` and do `git push origin master:master`, and branch `asdf` has nothing to do with this. In short, the branch the user is on is *private* information that your server has no business knowing.

Comment: What? No. The `pre-receive` hook *already* receives input. That input is documented in the hook man page. Go look at it. It gives you exactly what you need. (I don't know what your pre-receive hooks can be doing without already using this though. Nothing all that useful that I can image.)

Comment: @EtanReisner Stack Overflow prefers you provide an answer than to say "RTFM", or vote to close as being off-topic because it's too trivial.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this information?

Comment: @Schwern I'm aware of what preference is. I often choose not to bother writing up an answer which says "The manual says it works this way <quote> so you just need to use that" because it wastes my time and I'm sure someone who cares more about the rep will do that at some point. I also like to hope that the OP will notice that the answer was trivial and choose to delete their own question. The answer here isn't technically trivial even though it is directly from the manual.

Answer (score 3):

[Git push](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-push) doesn't assume any given branch is checked out locally; in fact, it could be a bare repository you're pushing. As Etan Reisner mentioned, [your script will automatically receive a list of *ref updates* on stdin](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#pre-receive), though, which can be used to tell which branches have new commits.

Comment: How can I use these ref-updates to find the local branch that it's committing to?

Comment: Think I see it.  The branch name is the basename of the third argument being passed into stdin to pre-receive.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple example of pre-receive hook

```
#! /bin/sh

while read oldrev newrev refname
do
    echo "$oldrev $newrev $refname"
done
```

`refname` contains the target branch refspec on the server (i.e. *refs/heads/master*)